# Изменение размера картинок

Tags: javascript, изображения, crop

Здравствуйте. Есть [сервис JavaScript image cropper](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/). При загрузке картинок они отображаются одного размера. Как этого добиться без искажения картинки?